# Closing a Kendo Grid editor template on click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I want to have a click event in the page, the event will fire when an item is clicked from my editor template, the event will close the editor template in that cell.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify your needs a little? Also if possible, add a simple demo (in dojo.telerik.com) of your grid. I can't figure what kind of *editor template* you're talking about.

Comment: This editor template: columns.Bound(c => c.Item).EditorTemplateName("DropDownTemplate");. So i want to have the drop down list editor close on click.

Comment: The cell will have to lose focus in order for the editor to close. Maybe look at the events for a dropdown and when a selection is made, move the focus to a different cell or off the grid.